# Is there any relation between the absolute value of eigenvalues and the numerical range?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Given a real non-symmetric matrix $A$, is there any relation between the absolute value of eigenvalues $|\lambda_i|$ and the numerical range $\{x^TAx:\|x\|=1\}$?
I need this for proving that the spectral radius of a non-symmetric $A$ is larger than one.

Note: When $A$ is symmetric then its numerical range $\{x^TAx:\|x\|=1\}$ coincides with the convex hull of its (indeed all real) eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but in case of symmetric matrix $A$ if $x^{T}Ax$ is positive than eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If there exists a vector $x$ such that $x^TAx>1$, can one conclude anything about the spectral raddi (given non-symmetric $A$)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Consider $A = \pmatrix{0 & r\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ which has numerical range $\{z: |z| \le r/2\}$ but spectral radius $0$.  So the fact that the numerical range contains some number won't give you a lower bound on the spectral radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robert has pointed out, the numerical range of $A$ numbers does not provide a lower bound on the spectral radius.
The numerical range contains the eigenvalues of $A$, but the spectral radius is defined in terms of the absolute values of the eigenvalues, so there's a bit of a mismatch here.
The best you could do here is say

$$\rho(A) \geq \min \left\{\left|x^TAx\right|\,:\,\lVert x \rVert = 1\right\},$$

but this won't help you much since the numerical range contains all eigenvalues -- including those with least absolute value.

What it *does* give you is a lower bound on the largest **singular value** of $A$.
Indeed, let${\lVert \cdot \rVert}_2$ be the Euclidian norm and ${\lVert\cdot\rVert}_{2,\text{op}}$ be the operator norm with respect to the Euclidian norm.
Then

\begin{align}
x^TAx
=
\langle x, Ax\rangle
&\leq
{\lVert x\rVert}_2
\,
{\lVert Ax\rVert}_2
\\&\leq
{\lVert x\rVert}_2
\,
{\lVert A\rVert}_{2,\text{op}}\, {\lVert x\rVert}_2
\\&=
{\lVert A\rVert}_{2,\text{op}}\, {\lVert x\rVert}_2^2
\\&\leq
{\lVert A\rVert}_{2,\text{op}}
\end{align}

It suffices to note that ${\lVert A\rVert}_{2,\text{op}}$ is the largest singular value of $A$.
Hence, $A$'s largest singular value is $\geq \max \left\{x^TAx\,:\,\lVert x \rVert = 1\right\}.$